# How to add a node to CMakeLists.txt to build the package?

Tags: ros, catkin-package, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a node in a package and it is working fine, now i added one more node to src folder of same package, how can i add the node to CMakeLists.txt to compile and run the package. Is there any automatic way to build the package without modifying the CMakeLists.txt, just by inserting the node to src folder.

---

Edit:  I have two nodes named **image_converter.cpp** and **image_invert.cpp** with same dependencies. My CMakeLists.txt is as follows. When i try to build it using cmake, i get the error as shown [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bh96p8mh4198wjz/ros%20error.png?dl=0). How to modify the CMakeLists.txt.

```
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
  project(opencv_pkg)

  find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  cv_bridge
  image_transport
  roscpp
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
  )

   include_directories(
     ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
   )

  add_library($image_convert src/image_converter.cpp)
  target_link_libraries($image_convert
    ${avcodec_LIBRARIES}
   ${swscale_LIBRARIES}
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
    )

   add_executable($image_convert_node src/image_converter.cpp)
   target_link_libraries($image_convert_node
    $image_convert
     ${avcodec_LIBRARIES}
   ${swscale_LIBRARIES}
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
    )

    add_library($image_invert src/image_invert.cpp)
    target_link_libraries($image_invert
     ${avcodec_LIBRARIES}
    ${swscale_LIBRARIES}
    ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
     )

   add_executable($image_invert_node src/image_invert.cpp)
   target_link_libraries($image_invert_node
    $image_invert
     ${avcodec_LIBRARIES}
     ${swscale_LIBRARIES}
    ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
    )
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213690/how-to-add-a-node-to-cmakelists.txt-to-build-the-package?/) by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 173 on 2015-07-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-07-14**:
@Kishore Kumar: please do not use answers to post updates to your question. Use the *edit* button for that (it's right under the main text of your question, with the little pen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, you **have to** specify this in the `CMakeLists.txt` manually. How should the compiler know which src and header files to compile together (besides magic. thanks for pointing this out in the comments ;-) )?

---

A problem I see in your `CMakeLists.txt` is the target name for your executables and libraries.
They should not start with a `$` sign. The dollar sign with curly brackets is for getting the values of variables, as it is done correctly below when linking against the `${catkin_LIBRARIES}` (I'm not sure if the other two exist).

so it should be:

```
  add_library(image_convert src/image_converter.cpp)
  target_link_libraries(image_convert
    ${avcodec_LIBRARIES}
    ${swscale_LIBRARIES}
    ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
  )

  add_executable(image_convert_node src/image_converter.cpp)
  target_link_libraries(image_convert_node
    image_convert
    ${avcodec_LIBRARIES}
    ${swscale_LIBRARIES}
    ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
   )

   add_library(image_invert src/image_invert.cpp)
   target_link_libraries(image_invert
     ${avcodec_LIBRARIES}
     ${swscale_LIBRARIES}
     ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
   )

   add_executable(image_invert_node src/image_invert.cpp)
   target_link_libraries(image_invert_node
     image_invert
     ${avcodec_LIBRARIES}
     ${swscale_LIBRARIES}
     ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
   )
```

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-07-14**:
jep must be done by

```
add_executable(node_name [files])
target_link_libraries(node_name [custom libraries ... ] {catkin_LIBRARIES} )
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-07-14**:\

> How should the compiler know which src and header files to compile together?

Magic? :)

**Comment by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on 2015-07-14**:
sry i cant get your point exactly, can u tell me where and how should i edit to fix it

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-07-14**:
You need to add the lines inside your CMakeLists.txt
There should be also some commented lines which should look like these, just comment them
insert the cpp files for [files] and a nodename of your choice for node_name [custom libraries ...] are optional and the catkin_LIBRARIES you always need.